# How do you create a sticky navigation when top of browser window is reached?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, sticky

I'm trying to get my navigation bar to stick to the top of the browser window once the header area has been scrolled passed. I wasn't thinking of it from the beginning so I've built the entire thing without the navigation being "fixed." I was hoping there'd be something I could do to make this happen without having to redo a bunch of my code.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Joshua Huff | Designer</title></title></title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="Google Fonts" href="" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <h1 id="logo">Joshua Huff</h1>
            <p id="logo-caption">You've gotta keep it real.</p>
            <p id="header-copyright">&copy; Joshua Huff 2014. All rights reserved.</p>


            <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->

            <nav id="menu-wrap">    
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Categories ▼</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">CSS ►</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
                                </ul>               
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Graphic design ►</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 21</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 22</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 23</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 24</a></li>
                                </ul>               
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Development tools ►</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 31</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 32</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 33</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 34</a></li>
                                </ul>               
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Web design ►</a>             
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 41</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 42</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 43</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Item 44</a></li>
                                </ul>   
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Work ▼</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Work 1 ►</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 11 ►</a>        
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 111</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 112</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 113</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 12 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 121</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 122</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 123</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 13 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 131</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 132</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 133</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                </ul>                   
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Work 2 ►</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 21 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 211</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 212</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 213</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 22 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 221</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 222</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 223</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 23 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 231</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 232</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 233 ►</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="">Work 2331</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="">Work 2332</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="">Work 2333</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="">Work 2334</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="">Work 2335</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                </ul>                   
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Work 3 ►</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 31 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 311</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 312</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 313</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 32 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 321</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 322</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 323</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Work 33 ►</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 331</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 332</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="">Work 333</a></li>
                                        </ul>                           
                                    </li>
                                </ul>                   
                            </li>
                        </ul>       
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    <li id="splitter">..</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- END OF NAVIGATION BAR -->

        </header>


        <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA LINKS -->

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/JoshuaMichaelHuff" target="_blank" class="social-link">       
            <img src="images/facebook-round.png" alt="Facebook logo" id="facebook" class="social-icon" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/JoshuaHuff94" target="_blank" class="social-link">     
            <img src="images/twitter-round.png" alt="Twitter logo" id="twitter" class="social-icon" />
        </a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/joshua_huff7812" target="_blank" class="social-link">     
            <img src="images/instagram-round.png" alt="Instagram logo" id="instagram" class="social-icon" />
        </a>

        <!-- END OF SOCIAL MEDIA LINKS -->


        <!-- PAGE CONTENT -->

        <div id="page-content">
            <section id="column-1">
                <h2>The Introduction to the Site</h2>
                <p>This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.</p>
                <br /><hr /><br />
                <h2>The Introduction to the Site</h2>
                <p>This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.</p>
                <br /><hr /><br />
                <h2>The Introduction to the Site</h2>
                <p>This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="column-2">
                <h2>The Introduction to the Site</h2>
                <p>This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.</p>
                <br /><hr /><br />
                <h2>The Introduction to the Site</h2>
                <p>This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.
                This is just going to be a way for me to test the color used for paragraphs.</p>
            </section>
        </div>

        <!-- END OF PAGE CONTENT -->


        <!-- SITE FOOTER -->

        <footer>
            <p id="footer-copyright">&copy; Joshua Huff 2014. All rights reserved.</p>
        </footer>

        <!-- END OF SITE FOOTER -->

    </body>
</html>
```

---

**CSS**

```
/*****************************
GENERAL
*****************************/


body{
    background: #eee;
    font: 13px 'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
}

h2 {
    color: #2f2e2a;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    color: #6e6b63;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #2A679F;
}

#page-content {
    text-align: left;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1100px;
    /*margin: 3% 10% 5% 10%;*/
    margin: 3% auto;
}

#column-1 {
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    /*padding-right: 14px;
    border-right: 1px solid #8e8e8d;*/
}

#column-2 {
    float: right;
    width: 480px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


/*****************************
HEADER
*****************************/


#logo {
    margin: 30px 0 0 125px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#logo-caption {
    margin: 0 0 0 125px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#header-copyright {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 125px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    color: #6e6b63;
    /*margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    color: #6e6b63;*/
}


/*****************************
NAVIGATION BAR
*****************************/


.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}

#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    max-width: 1080px;
    height: 38px;
    margin: /*60px*/ /*30px*/ 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));    
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
}

#menu:before, #menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /* IE6 only */
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);  
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;  
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /* IE6 only */
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);      
}

#menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border-left: 4px solid #aa0a0a;
    _line-height: 0; /* IE6 only */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    width: 130px;
    _height: 10px; /* IE6 only */
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0; 
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}


/*****************************
SOCIAL LINKS IN NAVIGATION BAR
*****************************/


#splitter {
    /*margin-left: 45px;*/
    margin-left: 305px;
    border-right: 2px solid #171715;
    font-size: 1px;
    height: 38px;
}

#facebook {
    margin-right: 275px;
}

#twitter {
    margin-right: 225px;
}

#instagram {
    margin-right: 175px;
}

.social-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    /*margin-top: -95px;*/ /*Only when the nav-bar is at 60px from margin-top */
    /*margin-top: -65px;*/ /*Only when the nav-bar is at 30px from margin-top */
    margin-top: -50px; /*Only when the nav-bar is at 15px from margin-top */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}


/*****************************
FOOTER
*****************************/


footer {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #8e8e8d;
}

.footer-social-link {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#footer-copyright {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: none;
    color: #6e6b63;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/ak3uM/)**</kbd>

```
(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 130) {
       $('#menu-wrap').addClass('fixed');   
    }
    else {
       $('#menu-wrap').removeClass('fixed');   
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

---

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#header-copyright {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 20px 125px 15px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  color: #6e6b63;
}
#menu {
  max-width: 1080px;
  height: 38px;
  margin: /*60px*/ /*30px*/ 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background-color: #111;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));    
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);  
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
}
.social-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -34px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :) This works great. ^.^ Out of curiosity, would you happen to know how I could get my social media links to stay in place along with it? I'm not sure if this will mean somehow changing my code and including them in the div or nav tag with the navigation or if I can do it without having to do that rearranging. I'd just like them to basically look like they're a part of the navigation bar. ^.^

Comment: In the fiddle I already put social icons in navigation `<li>` element so they are staying in navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be best off to use javascript for this. Here's a solution that relies on jQuery to convert the navbar positioning to fixed once it gets to the top of the page as well as stick a temporary div in its place to prevent the layout from changing.

http://jsfiddle.net/T6nZe/523/

HTML (Sample replace with yours):

```
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div class="navbar"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.fix {
  position: fixed;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  var
    $win = $(window),
    $filter = $('.navbar'),
    $filterSpacer = $('<div />', {
      "class": "filter-drop-spacer",
      "height": $filter.outerHeight()
    });
  $win.scroll(function(){     
    if(!$filter.hasClass('fix') && $win.scrollTop() > $filter.offset().top){
      $filter.before($filterSpacer);
      $filter.addClass("fix");
    } else if ($filter.hasClass('fix')  && $win.scrollTop() < $filterSpacer.offset().top){
      $filter.removeClass("fix");
      $filterSpacer.remove();
    }
  });
});
```